# Bubble Sort in O(n)?

Tags: bubble-sort

I know traditionally bubble sort is n^2 time complexity, but I wrote my own implementation of it and to me it looks O(n). I don't see how it can be n^2 because I don't have any nested loops. Even when I call it recursively in a loop, I break the loop right after the recursion.

```
def bubblesort(x):
    index = 0
    while index <= len(x) - 2:
        if x[index + 1] < x[index]:
            temp = x[index + 1]
            x[index + 1] = x[index]
            x[index] = temp
        else:
            index += 1
    print(index)
    index = 0
    while index <= len(x) - 2:
        if x[index + 1] < x[index]:
            bubblesort(x)
            break
        else:
            index += 1
```

Comment: There is the reason: you're making it complicated by bringing on the recursion! Recursive calls would add to the complexity as well.

Comment: If you ignore the recursive call then it's O(n), sure... but it makes O(n) recursive calls. Each recursive call only makes at most one other recursive call, but the call stack depth will be O(n). Try taking a list like `[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` and stepping through it with a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If I unwrap the tail recursion it's clearly a nested loop for O(N^2)

```
def bubblesort(x):
    do
        index = 0
        while index <= len(x) - 2:
            if x[index + 1] < x[index]:
                temp = x[index + 1]
                x[index + 1] = x[index]
                x[index] = temp
            else:
                index += 1
        print(index)
        index = 0
        while index <= len(x) - 2 and x[index + 1] >= x[index]:
            index += 1
    while index <= len(x) - 2 and x[index + 1] < x[index]
```

Comment: Even though recursive call is only called once? It only gets executed at the first instance of the right condition in the while loop, then the loop breaks after the call.

Comment: @phone1021: Put a print statement immediately before the recursive call.